# Odd or Even functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]This question is "Given that $H(x) = f(x)-g(x) $ and $f(3) = -4$ and $g(3)=2$ and $h(3)=-2$, which functions f and/or g (both or neither) is/are odd?"

I get completely stuck because $H(x)$ is listed with a capital $H$ and the $h(3)$ value is listed with lower case which makes me think they are not the same function at all.

I would have thought that $H(3) = f(3)-g(3) = -4-2=-6$ which does not equal $h(3)$ which is given as $-2$.

I fully understand that if $f(x)$ is even then $f(-3) = f(3)$ and if $f(x)$ is odd then $f(-3) = - f(3)=4$.

Difficult to see where to go from here.

Comment: I think the case difference is a typo in the question.

Comment: I thought about that, but shouldn't H(3) or h(3) = f(3)-g(3) = -6?  and it's given as -2

Comment: You are right, there is a mistake somewhere. Could you provide a link or a picture to the question ? Something like $H\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)$ ?

Comment: There really isn't a link.  It's a question from a past precalc test that I was studying from.  And it didn't list the answer.

Comment: I don't see a way to insert an image

Comment: There is one, edit your question and upload it

Comment: I uploaded the question.

Comment: I dont see the point giving $h(3)$ while he gives you $f(3)$ and $g(3)$.

Comment: I agree.  That's why I had no idea how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain it as I suppose it is. I can't be sure of what I'm saying. 
For me there is a little mistake which is $H\left(-3\right)=-2$ and not $H\left(3\right)=-2$ because as I said, there's no point giving you this because you have already $f(3)$ and $g(3)$. Then you have
$$
H\left(3\right)=-6 \text{ and }H\left(-3\right)=f\left(-3\right)-g\left(-3\right)=-2$$

$\bullet$ **Suppose that $f$ is even then**
$$
g\left(-3\right)=2+f\left(3\right)=-2=-g\left(3\right)
$$
which means both $f$ and $g$ are even and odd respectively. It is the same if i suppose first $g$ is even.
But i've not proved they were actually even or odd, if one is of a kind the other will be the other.

$\bullet$ **Suppose that $f$ is odd then**
$$
g\left(-3\right)=2-f\left(3\right)=6 \ne \pm g\left(3\right)
$$
With no more hypothesis on $h$, we can't tell nothing. They could be no odd/even functions too.

Comment: Ah ha!!!  I think I even see a little added negative sign in the problem added by the student probably from the teacher or the board.  This makes sense.

Comment: Now I see it too haha, that's it then. Furthermore, you can try to find a function that could fit the problem with no function being odd. It's easy to find such a function.